# Getting /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected when Trying to execute shell command (comm) on meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, shell, meteor

I'm trying to execute a (comm) command to compare 2 files line by line, **when I run the code directly from my terminal like this it works just fine**.

```
comm -3 <(sort ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/address/newList_md5.csv) <(sort ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/address/newSuppressionList.csv) > ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/Tercero.csv
```

but when I try to run it on my meteorjs server it just wont work for some reason that I can not understand, I've checked my code serveral times but I haven't found the solution.

**This function helps me execute shell commands:**

```
process_exec_sync = function (command) {

    var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");
    var child = Npm.require("child_process");
    var future = new Future();

    child.exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        var result = {};
        if (error) {
        result.error = error;
        }
        result.stdout = stdout;
        future.return(result);
    });
    return future.wait();
}
```

**here the piece of code that I'm trying to implement with the "comm" command but it always return an error in the meteorjs server**

```
lr.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    var suppression;
    var op;
    for(var sp = 0; sp < suppressionLists.length; sp++){
        suppression = SuppressionLists.findOne({_id: suppressionLists[sp]}).name;

        // -------------- This is what I'm having problems with -------------
        op = process_exec_sync("comm -3 <(sort ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/"+list.userId+"/"+listName+"_md5.csv) <(sort ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/"+list.userId+"/"+suppression+") > ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/Tercero.csv")
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    if (op.error) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("exec-fail", "Error running this: " + op.error.message);
        future['return']("error");
    }
    else
    {
        future['return']("success");
    }
}));
```

This is the error:

```
  I20161102-14:54:28.605(-4)? Exception in callback of async function: Error: Error running this: Command failed: /bin/sh -c sudo bash comm -3 <(sort ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/JCHWE8j9q7NnTbgE7/newList_md5.csv) <(sort ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/JCHWE8j9q7NnTbgE7/newSuppressionList.csv) > ~/jobs/suppression/server/maillists/Tercero.csv
    I20161102-14:54:28.605(-4)? /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
    I20161102-14:54:28.606(-4)?  [exec-fail]
    I20161102-14:54:28.611(-4)?     at app/server/methods.js:321:13
    I20161102-14:54:28.612(-4)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
```

Comment: It is using /bin/sh - that may be different from your default shell (bash?)

Comment: In the line starting **op = process_exec_sync** try using single quotes everywhere 'xxx' instead of double quotes "xxx"